# do some work in the background and return the result

Tags: multithreading, background, return-value, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to get the ID from a tag, using a library.

I came up with the following. the loop that's looks for a tag is done in the background and I get a correct result in tagAsString.

```
-(void) readTag {
    NSLog(@"readTag");
    unsigned char * tagUID = (unsigned char *) malloc(M1K_UID_SIZE * sizeof(char)); 
    //work to do in the background
    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        ERR ret;
        while ((ret = scanner->IsTagAvailable(tagUID)) != ERR_TAG_AVAILABLE) {
            NSLog(@"ret: %d", ret);
        }


        //main thread
        dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if(ret == ERR_TAG_AVAILABLE) {
                NSLog(@"tag available");
                NSString *tagAsString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%x%x%x%x", tagUID[0],tagUID[1],tagUID[2],tagUID[3]] retain];

            }
        });
    });
}
```

I would like to be able to return that value so I would be able to call:

```
NSString * myTag = [self readTag];
```

is that possible ? 
Thanks for your help, Michael

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is possible, however the problem with returning a string from that function is that it would need to hold up your calling thread whilst you perform the work in the background - thus losing the benefit of the background thread. (dispatch_sync is what you would use to do that - however I would not recommend it).

When using blocks it is best to restructure your program to fit better with the asynchronous paradigm. When the work is complete it should notify whatever is waiting on the result by sending a message to it with the result. In your example you would put this in the block of code you dispatch on the main queue.

```
@interface TagManager
- (void)fetchTag;
- (void)tagFetched:(NSString *)tag;
@end

@implementation TagManager
- (void)fetchTag {
    // The following method does all its work in the background
    [someObj readTagWithObserver:self];
    // return now and at some point someObj will call tagFetched to let us know the work is complete
}

- (void)tagFetched:(NSString *)tag {
    // The tag read has finished and we can now continue
}
@end
```

Then your readTag function would be modified as so:

```
- (void)readTagWithObserver:(id)observer {
    ...
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        ...
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           if (tag is ok) {
                [observer tagFetched:tag];
           }
        });
    });                          
}
```

The main idea is that you need to split your processing up into two stages

1. requesting that some work is done (fetchTag in my example)
2. process the result when it finishes (tagFetched: in my example)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you mean use a NSNotification to notify or is there any other way ?

Comment: NSNotification is one possible way, however in this example I would just use message passing (method calls). I will edit my answer with an example